# unter Stress **stehen**... not **sein** instead?

Tags: meaning

In the Langenscheidt I found this expression:

*unter Stress stehen   (1.)*

Then I consulted also the Duden:

*im S. sein; im/unter S. stehen   (2.)*

where S. stands for stress.

In other words, as far as the context of Stress is concerned, one can use the prepositions **in** and **unter** with stehen, but not with sein. More simply put, **I cannot say: unter Stress sein. Why not? Why does it work only with stehen? What are the subtle differences in imagery (which I am not catching) that these two verbs evoke, such that *unter* is possible with the first, but not with the latter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Unter Stress stehen* is a collocation. You can replace Stress with a handful of semantically similar [words](https://www.dict.cc/?s=unter%20etwas%20stehen), like *Spannung, Strom, Druck*, or remote words like *Arrest, Schutz, Beobachtung, Narkose, …*. Only with Stress, you have the equivalent option of *in/im … sein*.

As for imagery, which I do think is a great way to remember: Imagine your boss as a giant. He/she is treading on you. You're standing straight, raising your arms and bracing your body, struggling to not succumb under his/her sole.

Comment: Verstehe ich Dich richtig, dass man "Er ist in Schutz/Arrest/Narkose" nicht sagen kann?

Comment: @user _Er ist in/im Stress_ hört sich für mich ebenso nicht ungewöhnlich an.

Comment: @πάν: Willst Du damit sagen, dass Du das aus meiner Aussage schließt? Dem zweiten Absatz Cacambos kann ich übrigens nicht zustimmen; ich betrachte das "im Stress stehen" nicht als Hinweis auf eine widerständige Haltung, wobei ich mich gemütlich auf "unter Narkose stehen" berufen würde.

Comment: @us Ich will damit sagen, dass _unter_ im Kontext von _Stress_ nicht zwingend notwendig ist. _Unter Narkose stehen_, kann dagegen wohl kaum mit _in Narkose stehen_ ersetzt werden, da hast Du recht.

Comment: @userunknown "Er ist in/im Schutz/Arrest/Narkose" kann man nicht sagen, ja. Jedenfalls würde ich nicht das Gleiche verstehen wie *unter XYZ stehen*,

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "Er ist im Stress" finde ich auch total okay; "*in* Stress" nicht.

Comment: @userunknown Widerstand war eig. nicht das Konzept, was ich bewusst vermitteln wollte. Mir ging es eher darum, *Belastung* mit *stehen* zu verbinden. Das Bild kam mir als erstes. Andererseits: Bei Stress versuchen die meisten ja nicht sofort einzubrechen, sondern zu widerstehen. Bei Narkose gilt das natürlich nicht; der unterzieht man sich freiwillig.

Comment: @Cacambo: Nein, Narkose impliziert keine Freiwilligkeit. Arrest übrigens auch nicht.  "Unter Arrest stehen" und "in Arrest sein" sind wohl nicht 100% deckungsgleich, aber doch weitgehend, oder? Man könnte unter Arrest stehen, aber gerade ausgebrochen sein, dann wäre man nicht mehr in Arrest. Oder man könnte irrtümlich in Arrest sein, verwechselt man jmd., der unter Arrest steht. Stress dagegen ist ein psychisches Geschehen. Zw. unter Stress stehen und im Stress sein, da sehe ich wenig Raum für Unterschiede. P.S.: Was ist mit "Im Schutz der Dunkelheit"? Kann man nicht sagen?

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are correct and used in standard German:

"Ich bin unter Stress." is the same as "Ich stehe unter Stress."

You can use the forms synonymously.

The form "unter Stress stehen" is, maybe, a little more elegant.

Comment: I never heard "Ich **bin** unter Stress" - except in a construction like *Ich bin unter Stress leicht reizbar* (=Ich bin leicht reizbar, wenn ich unter Stress stehe)